# `setAppends([])` on relation which is being loaded by `with` in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So for my project model `setAppends([])` works as below:

```
Project::find($projectId)->setAppends([])
```

but what if I want to set appends to empty array for a relation which I'm eager loading with `with`, like below:

```
$project = Project::with('pages')->find($projectId);
```

`->setAppends([])` not working in above code, as it will set it to empty array for `Project` not for `Page`.

Can anyone guide how to achieve that ?

### Update:

`page.php` Model has appends and hidden like this:

```
class Page extends Model {
    // I don't want to load this (`appends`) attributes when I call Project::find($projectId)
    protected $appends = ['thumbnail_url', 'total_annotations', 'total_tasks', 'total_done_tasks', 'image_url', 'edited_data_items_count'];
    protected $hidden = ['tasksCount', 'doneTasksCount', 'annotationsCount', 'xsl', 'xml', 'dataxml_version', 'sort_order', 'editedDataItemsCount', 'deletedDataItemsCount'];
}
```

`Project.php` model looks like this:

```
class Project extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $appends = ['total_tasks', 'total_done_tasks', 'total_pages', 'total_annotations', 'edited_dataitems_total_count'];
    protected $hidden = ['tasksCount', 'doneTasksCount', 'pagesCount', 'annotationsCount', 'folder_path', 'attachment_url', 'pages'];
}
```

Comment: what is your current output and what is expected ?, Did you tried `whereHas('pages')` ?

Comment: in `Page` model there are multiple `appends`, I don't want to load those as it's not needed. I havn't tried whereHas

Comment: You mean you want to filer from `pages` ? like to add `where` condition ?

Comment: No, There are comments tasks etc. which are loading when I load `Page` by default. But I don't want that in this particular case. Means I don't want to load all relations for related to pages.

Comment: `whereHas('page')` is not working even.

Comment: Why don't you use `->select('field1', 'field2')` to get needed properties?

Comment: @AlexSlipknot How select will work with dynamic attributes that are not in db? e.g. in `Project` model I have attribute `total_tasks`, which is not in DB, rather there's method `getTotalTasksAttribute`.

Comment: @shyammakwana.me ah, sorry for misunderstanding. But still not clear. I can't understand why don't you use different class instead?

Comment: What do you mean by class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Project you may provide a static method, which allows you to iterate over the eagerly loaded pages and adjust their append-array.

```
    class Project
    {
        ... 

        public static function eagerFindWithoutAppends($projectId) 
        {
            $model = self::with('pages')->find($projectId);
            $model->setAppends([]);

            foreach ($model->pages as $page) {
                $page->setAppends([]);
            }

            return $model;
        }

        ...        
    }
```

But if I understand correctly, the dynamic data in your Pages class does more than just providing convenient shortcuts based on the regularly loaded data (such as something like getFullName which would combine first_name and last_name).

What do your appends do?

> I don't want to load this (`appends`) attributes

Another possible solution I could think of is to inherit NoneAppendPages from Pages and override $append and all the related get... methods.

Then in Project declare another relationship to NoneAppendPages next to Pages. You then eager `load Project::::with('none_append_pages')->find($projectId);`

```
class NoneAppendPages extends Pages
{

    protected $appends = [];

    getYourDynamicAttributeMethodName() { return null; } // for all your appends

}

class Project
{
    public function pages()
    {
       // I don't know what relationship you declared / assuming on to many
        return $this->hasMany('App\Page');
    }

    public function noneAppendPages()
    {
       // declare the same way you did with pages
        return $this->hasMany('App\NoneAppendPage');
    }

}
```

Comment: appends in `Page` does some counts, groupbys, eager load it's belongsTo relations. And those are not needed in some cases. That's why I want to get rid of this.

Comment: First approach looks appealing, I'll try. Can you provide an example for second approach (NoneAppendPages) ?

Comment: So your appends load further relations? In that case I think approach one won't work - haven't checked it myself yet.

Comment: Yeah it loads further, but that's not required in some cases, so I can call static method whenever it's needed. Thus, approach one worked like charm. Thanks for saving my day. I was thinking in making this one liner code only, that's why I didn't get strike.

Comment: Great that it works for you. I added more details for the second approach, which - however - I don't really like.

Comment: I see. I don't like this even. In this is this `getYourAppendOne()` required ?

Comment: I changed the name to getYourDynamicAttributeMethodName to make it more clear that it is/are the getter/s for your dynamic attribute/s. It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. IMO - again - the second approach seems like solving a problem that might have a different cause. I don't like it.

Comment: If the first approach works for you, then I guess the problem you are trying to solve is to avoid loading the Page relations when casting the Project model to an array or JSON. Is that correct?

Comment: Second approach is to make it more dynamic the way you want. But one is short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

The given solution does not work when using a package that does a lot of the work after you define the `with()` relations like `datatables`

here is a solution that works for any model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Database;

trait Appendable {

    static protected $static_appends = [];
    static protected $static_replace_appends = null;

    /**
     * set a static appends array to add to or replace the existing appends array..
     * replace => totally replaces the existing models appends array at time of calling getArrayableAppends
     * add => merges and then makes unique. when getArrayableAppends is called. also merges with the existing static_appends array
     *
     * @param $appendsArray
     * @param bool $replaceExisting
     */
    public static function setStaticAppends($appendsArray, $replaceExisting = true)
    {
        if($replaceExisting) {
            static::$static_replace_appends = true;
            static::$static_appends = array_unique($appendsArray);
        } else {
            static::$static_replace_appends = false;
            static::$static_appends = array_unique(array_merge(static::$static_appends,$appendsArray));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the appendable values that are arrayable.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getArrayableAppends()
    {
        if(!is_null(static::$static_replace_appends)) {
            if(static::$static_replace_appends) {
                $this->appends = array_unique(array_merge(static::$static_appends,$this->appends??[]));
            } else {
                $this->appends = static::$static_appends;
            }
        }
        return parent::getArrayableAppends();
    }

}
```

then you can just apply the trait to any model

```
<?php

namespace App\Database;

abstract class Company
{
    use Appendable;
}
```

then call the static method BEFORE you use the relationship

```
<?php

$replaceCurrentAppendsArray = true;
// this will remove the original appends by replacing with empty array
\App\Database\Company::setStaticAppends([],$replaceCurrentAppendsArray);

$replaceCurrentAppendsArray = true;
// this will remove the original appends by replacing with smaller array
\App\Database\Company::setStaticAppends(['thumbnail_url'],$replaceCurrentAppendsArray);

$replaceCurrentAppendsArray = FALSE;
// this will add to the original appends by providing an additional array element
\App\Database\Company::setStaticAppends(['my_other_attribute'],$replaceCurrentAppendsArray);
```

this will allow you to override the appends array provided on the model even if another package is going to be loading the model. Like `yajra/laravel-datatable` where my issue was and brought me to this page which inspired a more dynamic solution.

This is similar to Stefan's second approach, but this is more dynamic so you do not have to create additional model extensions to accomplish the overrides.

You could take a similar approach to override the `HidesAttribute` trait as well.

Comment: Posted on my gist for my future reference :)  https://gist.github.com/Artistan/50cc06379fc2ab829ad00313fd0a8b61

Comment: Not working for me I have also commented on your github 

I am using datatables,here is the code snippet from my controller

 $replaceCurrentAppendsArray = true;
                    Product::setStaticAppends([],$replaceCurrentAppendsArray);
                    Brand::setStaticAppends([],$replaceCurrentAppendsArray);
                    ProductCategory::setStaticAppends([],$replaceCurrentAppendsArray);
                    $query = Product::with(['categories', 'tags', 'brand', 'created_by'])
                    ->select(
                        'products.*'
                    );